# SQL Server execute view with owner account

Tags: sql-server

I want to push data to Excel from a restricted table.

I've created a view and pull the data from the table, now an Excel account has been granted to access the view but still can't get the data.

What's the best option here,

- `owner access option`, if possible at all in SQL Server (making the view run as dbo, even when called from Excel user) - may be counter-security
- Stored procedure?

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored procedure drove me all the way home.